# calculate two random numbers

Tags: java

I'm still a basic guy in javascript, I'm trying to do a small quiz that is the user to enter their name and kind of skill ( easy, so so, hard ), after that they will move to the basic calculator, the basic calculator is if the user selected easy skill it will show to them two randomly numbers that is from 1 to 99 and it will be added only since It will be hard for me to do random operations. so if he enter the correct answer of the two random addition question it will update the score and will add 1 to the right counter, otherwise, it will be added 1 to the wrong counter.

below is my code and I'm sticking on how to do the calculation things, I was trying to do it but spent hours and hours on it, I looked at google but all the ways that with all operations while I need it only for the addition thing only .. how could I fix my issue?

Comment: `if(correctAnswer){ ... } else { ... }` - What do you expect from this "condition"? `correctAnswer` is the sum of the two random numbers. Unless they are both zero (which isn't possible with your script) the condition will always evaluate as `true`

Answer (score 2):

You're very much there.

First I suggest in your HTML use input type number. (or throw an error to the user if the submit is not a number)

```
<input type="**number**" id="answer" >
```

As for your JS.

You are not grabbing the answer from the user input. Your variable **answer** is not in use, in your function **checkTheAnswers()**

So you can do that. **answer = parseInt(answer);** - this way you turn it into a number type. (you can also use Number(answer).

--
Next take a look at your if statement. You're basically saying if **correctAnswer** is true do something. (as Andreas said in the comments)

What you want to do is, to check it against your **answer** variable. (after grabbing it's value)

So if **(answer === correctAnswer)** - do something.

Also variables **right** and **wrong** need to stay out of the function, otherwise anytime you run the function they'll reset back to 0.

At the end there're many ways to write it, I figure a simple and clean way as the following. This way you have total sum, right, wrong.

There it is.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function () {

  document.forms[0].addEventListener("submit", afterLogin);
  document.getElementById("submit2").addEventListener("click", checkTheAnswers);
  document.forms[0].name.addEventListener("input", stringValidation);
  document.getElementById("reset").addEventListener("click", resetForm);
  let radios = document.querySelectorAll("[type=radio]");
  let submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");
  let userName = document.forms[0].name;
  let answer = document.forms[1].answer;
  let errorMsg = document.getElementById("nameMsg");
  let error = document.getElementById("error");
  let skillMsg = document.getElementById("skillMsg");
  let welcome = document.getElementById("welcome");
  let loginForm = document.getElementById("login");
  let calForm = document.getElementById("cal");
  let num1 = document.getElementById("firstNum");
  let num2 = document.getElementById("secondNum");
  let isTrue = false;
  submitButton.disabled = true;
  calForm.style.display = "none";

  function stringValidation() {
    if (this.value === "") {
      errorMsg.innerHTML = "your name shoudn't be blank";
      isTrue = true;
      submitButton.disabled = true;
    } else {
      errorMsg.innerHTML = "";
      isTrue = false;
      if (!isTrue) {
        submitButton.disabled = false;
      }
    }
  }
  function afterLogin(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    for (let i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
      if (!radios[i].checked) {
        skillMsg.innerHTML = "Please check one of the skills before login";
      } else {
        welcome.innerHTML = "Welcome " + userName.value;
        loginForm.style.display = "none";
        calForm.style.display = "block";
      }
    }
    startTheGame();
  }

  function startTheGame() {
    for (let i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
      if (radios[i].checked) {
        let tt = radios[i].value;
        switch (tt) {
          case "easy":
            easy();
            break;
          case "soso":
            soso();
            break;
          case "hard":
            hard();
            break;
          default:
            error.innerHTML = "something went wrong ..!";
        }
      }

    }

  }

  function easy() {
    rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (99 - 5)) + 5;
    rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (99 - 5)) + 5;
    num1.innerHTML = rand1;
    num2.innerHTML = rand2;


  }
  function soso() {
    error.innerHTML = "soso";
  }
  function hard() {
    error.innerHTML = "hard";
  }

  let right = 0;
  let wrong = 0;

  function checkTheAnswers() {
    
    let correctAnswer = rand1 + rand2;

    let userAnswer = parseInt(answer.value);

    if (userAnswer === correctAnswer) {
      right++
    } else {
      wrong++
    }
    
    error.innerHTML = right - wrong;
    loginForm.style.display = "none";

    easy();
  }

  function resetForm() {
    errorMsg.innerHTML = "";
    skillMsg.innerHTML = "";
    userName.value = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
      radios[i].checked = false;
    }
    submitButton.disabled = true;

  }


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <title>Solutions</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="js.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="page">
    <h1>Calculator Game</h1>
    <div id="error"></div>
    <!-- login form -->
    <form id="login">
        <label>Enter your name : <span id="nameMsg"></span></label><br>
        <input type="text" id="name"><br>
        
        <label>Select your skill : <span id="skillMsg"></span></label><br>
        
        <input type="radio" id="easy" name="skill" value="easy">
        <label for="easy">easy</label>
        <input type="radio" id="soso" name="skill" value="soso">
        <label for="soso">so so</label>
        <input type="radio" id="hard" name="skill" value="hard">
        <label for="hard">hard</label><br>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" >
        <input type="button" id="reset" value="reset" ><br>
    </form>
    <br>

    <!-- Calculator form -->
    <div id="welcome"></div>
    <form id="cal">
    <span id="firstNum"></span>
    <span id="operator">+</span>
    <span id="secondNum"></span><br>
    <input type="number" id="answer" ><br><br>
    <input type="button" id="submit2" value="submit2" >
    <input type="button" id="reset2" value="reset" >
    </form>




</div>
</body>

</html>
```